# Swift: I have to call Facebook loginbutton twice to get an FBSDKAccessToken

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My issue is: I have to press the Facebook Login button twice to get a FBSDKAccessToken. After that, the token is persistent throughout the use of the app. Upon the first button press, the AccessToken seem to be there and 'dissapears' again after the observer is getting called four times.

Same happens when I move the observer to my viewDidAppear() and if I uncomment the 'FBSDKProfile.enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true)' line.

I have the following code:
In my AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Let Facebook API know we finished launching         
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    return true
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Register actions, such as add clicks and app FB statistics
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

In my LoginOrSignupViewController

```
class LoginOrSignupViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var buttonFacebooklogin: FBSDKLoginButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Customize the facebookLogin button   
    buttonFacebooklogin.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
    buttonFacebooklogin.delegate = self
    //FBSDKProfile.enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(listenForFBLogin), name: FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}
```

In my viewDidAppear() I have some print statements. As well as in my Facebook login button. What I notice is that the Observer function gets called 4 times, the first two times there is a AccessToken, the last two times there isn't.

When I press the Facebook Login button again, it acts like it should. 
Print statements:

**First time I press the Login button:**

```
Observer listenForFBLogin function...
We got a token here...
<FBSDKAccessToken: 0x7fa0896b5f40>
Observer listenForFBLogin function...
We got a token here...
<FBSDKAccessToken: 0x7fa0896b5f40>
Observer listenForFBLogin function...
Even in the listenForFBLogin the Accestoken is empty...
Observer listenForFBLogin function...
Even in the listenForFBLogin the Accestoken is empty...
User is not logged in...
```

**The second time I press the Login button:**

```
Observer listenForFBLogin function...
We got a token here...
<FBSDKAccessToken: 0x7fa08b8407b0>
Observer listenForFBLogin function...
We got a token here...
<FBSDKAccessToken: 0x7fa08b8407b0>
Tickee isUserLoggedIn: Logged in with Facebook and Firebase...
User is logged in, go to the tabbar...
```

**My Facebook login code**

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

    if error != nil {
        // Error login
        NSLog("Error van loginButton func:")
        NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
    } else if result.isCancelled {
        // User cancelled login
        // NSLog("User cancelled Facebook login")
    } else {

        // User logged in. Proceed to request Auth from Firebase

        // Signup or Login with Firebase
        let firebaseRef = Firebase(url: "https://tickee.firebaseio.com/")
        let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString

        // Auth the User in Firebase
        firebaseRef.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", token: accessToken, withCompletionBlock: {
            (error, authData) in

            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog("Login failed")
            } else {

                // Check if UID is saved to UserDefaults
                let userUID = self.tickee.getUserUIDFromUserDefaults()

                // Check if UID exists
                if userUID == nil {

                    // UID doesn't not exists, there is no user
                    print("User doesn't exist yet, create new Facebook user in Firebase...")

                    // Create User in Firebase
                    self.tickee.createUserInFirebase("facebook", nameField: nil)

                    // Save UID in NSUserDefaults
                    self.tickee.saveUserUIDtoNSUserDefaults()
                } else {
                    print("User exists already, no need to create one again...")
                }

                print("Done loggin in, now wait for the observer...")

            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the viewDidLoad() I asked the View if user was logged in. When loggin in with Facebook and Authing with Firebase there's a couple of asynchronous functions. The result isn't properly processed yet, so the viewDidLoad called to soon.

I removed processing the result after the loading is complete in the login function itself and no longer in viewDidLoad()